# How does the TabBarController stay always visible?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, iad

I have been trying to find why the TabBarController is always visible. I have been trying to implement an iAd that doesn't reload every time I change View Controllers. I was able to implement this with an app that uses TabBarController, by appending the iAd to the TabBar, however, I another app that doesn't use the tabBarController I want to do the same thing, and I have not found a way to implement this. I have found several suggestions, here and there, but they are all, either, very complicated or don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabBarController` is somewhat the container of all the other `UIViewController`s. Everything is happening inside it. `UINavigationController` behaves the same.

In order for a `UIView` to be visible on all other `UIViewController`s you can:

1. Create your app inside a `UIView Container` and add the persistent `UIView` to that container
2. Add your `UIView` as a subview of `UINavigationController` view

In your first `UIViewController`:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:myView];
```